# Prove $\tau$ is cofinite on $X$ iff $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$-space and any infinite subset of $X$ is dense in $(X, \tau)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I dont have a clue about the proof in the reverse implication on the iff statement.

I will show what I have by now:

1) A cofinite topology implies that any infinite subset in $X$ is dense. Let $U\in\tau$ and is cofinite topology so $U=X-\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\}$.

Let $V\in X$ an infinite subset then $$V\cap U=V\cap(X-\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\})=(V\cap X)-(V\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\})=V-(V\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\})$$

and cause $|V|\ge\aleph_0$ and $|\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\}|=n\in\Bbb N\,$ we have that $|V\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\}|\le n$. And finally is obvious that $V-(V\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\{x_k\})\ne\emptyset$ so any infinite subset is dense on $X$.

2) A cofinite topology implies a $T_1$-space. Let $x, y\in X$ and $U\in\tau: U=X-\{y\}$ so $x\in U\land y\notin U$. We can define too $V\in\tau:V=X-\{x\}$ so $x\notin V\land y\in V$ then a cofinite topology is a $T_1$-space.

But my problem is that I dont have a clue to prove the reverse implication i.e. if we have a $T_1$-space where every infinite subset is dense then it is a cofinite topology. Some hint? Some advice or correction in the proof of above? Thank you in advance.

---

I will complete the proof with the advice of @Cameron Buie.

1) A $T_1$-space implies that any finite subset is closed. Let the singleton $\{x\}\subset X$. Then $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}\cup\{x\}'$ where $\{x\}'=\{y:(\forall U\in\tau : y\in U)\land x\in U\}$, but because we are in a $T_1$-space exist some $U$ for any points $x,y\in X: x\in U\land y\notin U$ so $\{x\}'=\emptyset$ then $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}$ and is closed.

This means that for every $T_1$-space it cofinite sets are open.

2) If any infinite subset is dense on $X$ it means that the closure of any infinite subset is $X$ so the only closed sets are finite (and $X$ itself), so the topology is cofinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: A space is $T_1$ if and only if every finite subset is closed. In other words, a space is $T_1$ if and only if every cofinite subset is open.

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if you have any other questions about this, or if you just want to check your proof with somebody.

Comment: I will write the second part of the proof now just to complete the question and if you want to says something is fine.